# Go - monetary calculations

Tags: go

I am trying to do monetary calculations with Go.

Looking around the standard library, `big/math` seems to be the one I can make use of.
And I ran some codes to check how it works.

First I used `Float.SetFloat64()`

```
var f = 18.9
var f2 = 1.65
bf := new(big.Float)
bf.Add(bf, new(big.Float).SetFloat64(f))
bf.Add(bf, new(big.Float).SetFloat64(f2))
result, _ := bf.Float64()
fmt.Println(result)
```

This gives me the result: `20.549999999999997`
Just like the calculation with `float64` type.
Since I'm dealing with money, the result must be `20.55`.

Instead, when using `Float.SetString()`

```
var s = fmt.Sprintf("%f", 18.9)
var s2 = fmt.Sprintf("%f", 1.65)
bf := new(big.Float)
bf2, _ := new(big.Float).SetString(s)
bf3, _ := new(big.Float).SetString(s2)
bf.Add(bf, bf2)
bf.Add(bf, bf3)
result, _ := bf.Float64()
fmt.Println(result)
```

This gives me the result: `20.55`
It SEEMs I can use this for my purpose (but I am not sure..).

My questions are

1. Why the difference beteween using `Float.SetFloat64()` and `Float.SetString()`?
2. Are there any pitfalls when using `Float.SetString()` for monetary calculations?

Thanks in advance, and forgive my English.

[EDIT]

I know float types should be avoided for representing money value.
but the choice of the type is not really under my control..

I want to know the answers to either(or both) of the above two questions.

Or the reason why `Float.SetString()` gives me the seemingly correct results is also helpful.

Comment: for dealing with money in Go - i have found this package to be quite useful https://github.com/shopspring/decimal

Comment: @syllabix Thank you. I will check that also.

Comment: I would hazard you against using floats for money ever. Especially if transactions are involved. Use integers.

Comment: Floats don't precisely represent decimal amounts because decimal is base 10 and floats are base 2. You can try 0.1+0.2 or your examples in Python or JavaScript, for example. You could start with `type Cents int` -- [here's an example](http://play.golang.org/p/ZKQipDT-gM) with (as the code says) no promise of correctness.

Comment: What is the reason you "have" to use floats? You shouldn't seek to be the one responsible for implementing currency handling in floats.

Answer (score 11):

Never, ever, never use float for currency. Its an imprecise type, so you end up having to round calculations off and you end up losing (or gaining) a penny here and there. You may think that's ok but your accountant will be able to tell you its not. You *have* to be perfectly accurate.

So either use an specialised arbitrary-precision decimal type, or use an integer and hold pennies (or fractions of a penny) and display it appropriately. (just like how you hold dates as seconds since 1970, yet display them as dd-mm-yyyy).

PS. Never use floats for currency. Really.

PPS. Do not use floats for currency, not ever never ever.

Comment: I know that..
I edited my question.
Hope you answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `big.Int` values representing 1000ths or 10000ths of a cent. Floating point values are not appropriate for money, especially when transacting. If somebody is demanding that you use floating point values, try to convince them it's a bad idea. If that doesn't work, reconsider your decision to work with them. Consider that you may inadvertently be involving yourself with something illegal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing

In answer to your technical question:

`big.Float` values are not arbitrary precision like `big.Int` values.

`SetFloat64` sets the precision of the float to that of a `float64` while `SetString` sets it based on what the contents of the string are.

Either way you want to be very deliberate about what precision you are setting on a big.Float value. You can control this with `SetPrec` https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.SetPrec

**Edit:**

As for pitfalls, consider that 0.10 in base 10 does not have a finite representation in base 2. Since `big.Float` doesn't have a `base` field or anything corresponding to that it can't actually store 0.10 exactly.

Basically as soon as you use the Float as a floating point number instead of as an integer you will leave exact values behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gopkg.in/inf.v0** which implements "infinite-precision" decimal arithmetic.

For your specified amounts above, here's an e.g.:

`func main() {
    var amt inf.Dec
    amt.SetUnscaled(1890)
    amt.SetScale(2)
    fmt.Println(amt.String())
    var amt1 inf.Dec
    amt1.SetUnscaled(165)
    amt1.SetScale(2)
    fmt.Println(amt1.String())
    var total = inf.NewDec(5, 2)
    total = total.Add(&amt, &amt1)
    fmt.Println(total.String())
}`

It should print out 20.55 as expected.